# Формирование потоков блоками до EOF

Tags: sql, delphi, файлы, потоки-данных

Есть интересная задумка:

Парсить текстовый файл для вставки данных в базу данных. Данные в текстовом файле через символ **;**. Строки через **chr(13)chr(10)**

Данные, то есть, храняться так:

- value1;value2;value3;chr(13)chr(10)
- value1;value2;value3;chr(13)chr(10)

Работаю с потоками: создаю поток, в котором обрабатываю по очереди строки и собираю их в скрипт, который потом хочу выполнить разом, чтобы занести данные в базу. На данном этапе по нажатию на кнопку запускается один поток, который начинает с самого начала обрабатывать строки в файле **TFileStream** и заносит их в **TStringList** в виде "**Insert into Table1 (value1,value2,value3)**"

Хотелось бы понять, а можно по нажатию на кнопке запускать процесс создания по четыре потока где каждый, к примеру, обрабатывает по 50 строк максимум. Так сделать, чтобы потоки перепрыгивали через друг друга?

То есть:

Есть 270 строк предположим. Создаются четыре потока по 50 строк, то есть:

- Поток 1 - 0..50
- Поток 2 - 50..100
- Поток 3 - 100..150
- Поток 4 - 150..200

А по завершению поток перебрасывается на следующий блок начиная со строки, которую возможно или даже скорее всего нужно передавать в переменную и оттуда брать. То есть по завершению тех четырёх потоков, который быстрее закончил идёт дальше.

Предположим 1 и 3 потоки закончили первыми:

- Поток 1 - 200..250
- Поток 3 - 250..270 (тут возникает ещё одна сложность, как узнать, что их там меньше 50?)

Такое вообще возможно?

Таким образом можно было бы ускорить работу в разы и передавать значения в базу блоками по 50.

Comment: Судя по описанию - это csv-файл, простейшая таблица. Вероятно, для вашей СУБД уже есть штатные средства для работы с csv. Которые будут использовать быстрые операции вставки (BULK INSERT кажется) и т.п.

Comment: Похож на *csv-файл*, но он в расширении ***.txt** Загружаю в Firebird с помощью FireDac на Delphi XE.

Comment: Расширение файла неважно. Пусть хоть bin будет. Ускорение за счет потоков в данном случае тоже довольно сомнительно: считается, что работа с файловой системой - достаточно медленная операция по сравнению с работой в памяти. И произвольный (а не последовательный) доступ к файлу тоже не будет способствовать ускорению. Если файл небольшой (270 строк - это очень мало) - проще сразу загрузить его в память полностью. У вас 2 бутылочных горлышка - чтение из файла и запись в базу. Вот первое что попалось про ускорение вставки в базу: http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq209/

Comment: *каждый, к примеру, обрабатывает по 50 строк максимум. Так сделать, чтобы потоки перепрыгивали через друг друга?* Только при условии, что длина каждой строки в байтах есть константа для всего файла. Иначе для поиска места, где начинается очередной текстовый блок, необходимо прочитать все данные от текущей точки до требуемой, отсчитывая переводы строк.

Comment: @Akina А если использовать TBufferedFileStream и номера строк? Я нашел этот материал: [Faster FileStream with TBufferedFileStream](https://delphiaball.co.uk/2016/04/29/faster-filestream-tbufferedfilestream) как раз по компоненту FireDac, что можете сказать?

Comment: Как уже было сказано @kami, главным узким местом обычно является чтение с диска. Параллельное чтение могло бы помочь если бы ваши данные лежали бы на разных дисках. Многопоточное чтение с одного диска чаще оказывается медленнее последовательного чтения одним процессом из-за накладных расходов

Comment: *А если использовать TBufferedFileStream и номера строк?* Ну так это и есть ничто иное как  считывание ВСЕГО (а не только тех строк, которые запрошены).

Comment: Я бы предложил воспользоваться пайпами из OmniThreadLibrary. Задача разбивается на 2 части: чтение из файла с разбиением на элементы и запись в базу. Вот такая организация работы действительно минимизирует задержки. Грубо говоря (если не знакомы с Omni) - действует 2 потока: один читает из файла, второй записывает в базу.

Comment: @kami Is it this [OmniThreadLibrary](http://www.omnithreadlibrary.com/)   you are talking about?

Comment: @SovereignSun да. Возможно, для задачи из вопроса лучше всего подойдет http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2010/11/multistage-processes-with.html

Answer (score 0):

Операция действительно выполняется медленно, чтобы пытаться её распараллеливать? При такой архитектуре самое узкое место скорее всего будет при выполнении БД бесчисленных "Insert into ...", а не на распарсивании файла.
Тут лучше почитайте про "bulk insert", если такое есть в выбранной БД.

Если же хочется распараллелить именно парсинг файла, то мне кажется оптимальным такой алгоритм:

- один основной поток читает весь файл, делит файл на N частей (100 КБайт можно поделить на 5 частей по 20 КБ допустим)
- создает N потоков и каждому "скармливает" свой кусок файла
- ждет завершения работы N потоков (в среднем они должны завершиться более менее в одинаковое время)
- агрегирует результаты всех потоков в одну структуру

Таким образом можно распараллелить парсинг. При этом распараллеливать само чтение файла смысла нет.
По ходу нужно будет решить проблему правильного деления на N частей, потому что каждому потоку, очевидно, нужно будет скармливать целое количество строк.

Также может занять заметное время агрегация всех данных после завершения работы доп. потоков, если написать не оптимально - то это время может убить всю идею распараллеливания.

Comment: Я ещё думал сделать так: загрузить весь файл в память, потом одним потоком его пропарсить, а другим занести данные в таблицу. Тут возникает вопрос, как лучше парсить? Заносить строки в TStringList и потом перелавать TStringList в качестве скрипта или же сохранять как некий bulk для последующего insert?

Comment: 1) если один поток полностью пропарсит файл, то зачем для занесения в таблицу использовать второй поток? Пусть после парсинга сам и заносит. 2) использовать TStringList или массив строк, или еще что - не вижу особой разницы, как удобнее. 3) естественно, создание bulk-файла по правилам БД и выполнение bulk insert в разы будет быстрее, чем множество однотипных insert.